Maven repository URLs changed - resolution of transitive dependencies
Our DOAAS provider (in-house) previously had Nexus and for some reason decided to use "nexus" in the URL to the repositories.
Now they have switched to Gitea and the URLs have changed...which has of course created chaos in our many projects/POMs.  Their new default URLs also contained "gitea" in the URLs.
I managed with a lot of effort to convince them to provide generic URLs without the artifactory product-name in the URLs...so that in the future if they switch to artifactory "foobar" we don't need to switch everything again.
So now I am tasked with cleaning up our POMs for our master development and currently supported maintenance branches because those old "nexus" URLs will eventually be disabled (currently redirected to Gitea).
Finally to my question.
We have three repositories in every project - lets call them A (releases), B (thirdparty) and C (snapshots).  The repositories/pluginRepositories/distribution blocks are in the POMs because downstream projects use our artifacts.
Our main product development has dependencies on our own third-party JARs in these three repositories.  The 'id's of these servers have not changed - only the URLs.
Is it enough to override the URLs for the server ids in the main project POMs?  Will those overrides be used when evaluating the transitive dependencies in the third-party POMs?  Or is each third-party POM an island which will use those repository URLs defined there?
Asked another way, do I have to create new releases of all of those third-party JARs/POMs with the updated URLs and update all references to them?
NOTE: I don't want a solution with 'mirrorOf' in the settings.xml because a lot of customer projects use our build artifacts and that will create an entirely different kind of chaos since those settings are not under our control.
I couldn't find anything in the Maven documentation about how repository definition/resolution propagates to transitive dependencies.

OK I did find the answer to my own question hidden in a one-liner in the Maven documentation.

Each repository must have a unique ID. Clashing repository IDs within either effective settings or effective POMs lead to build failures. However, repositories from POM get overwritten by repositories with the same ID from effective settings. Repository IDs are also used in the local repository metadata.

(https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html#repository-ids)
So overriding the same repository id should update the effective POM and resolve against those repositories.
